# what is parameterisation concept in HP ALM ?

Tags: alm

i need help on HP ALM Parameterization concept.  what is use of Parameterization concept in HP ALM. how can we implement this concept ? give me any examples

Answer (score 0):

In terms of manual test cases, parametrization comes very handy when you have scenarios that have pretty much same steps or at least same structure. 
When you create a new test case,  you will have a button to parameters on the header menu, you can list all the parameters you think you would need. For a simple login test on multiple pages ( home page, account page ) with similar layout, you will have username, password and url as parameters. It also allows you to give default value.  You can add more parameter as you write steps in the step description window.

once you have the complete test case created, go to test configuration tab of the test case and add test configuration by clicking plus button. There will be one by default. You can create as many test configuration as you want. For above example you can add three; one for home page, one for account page and one for search page. The test configuration will help you have the test instances ready while pulling the test cases into test lab without having to drag the same test cases multiple times. 
The test configuration allows you to define the actual/default value for each of configuration added reducing the time it takes to fill this info during execution.

Test execution - after you pull the test cases into lab, during the manual run a pop up comes to show the values for each of parameter being used for that test case. Te values can be added or updated.
Please find a video I found on YouTube.

https://youtu.be/vCrJcHrosio

I don't have ALM to show with diagrams. Hope this helps.

Create a test testcase to test this feature. 
Thanks 
Happy exploring !!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters help the user to assign a value to a variable so as to execute the same test with different sets of data.

For example, the user name and password can be two parameters, for a login related test, which would be assigned with a value.

How to use parameters:

1. Create test case with steps in Test Plan module under selected Cycle and proper folder.
2. Select the test step against which you would like to add the parameter. The 'Parameter' Icon will be enabled. Click on the same. The 'Parameter' dialog box will open. Now, click on 'New Parameter' button. Add the parameter (here: username or password). Add the default and/or actual values, description for the same and save.
3. You can also add different test configurations to use these parameters for different use case scenarios.

More details can be found here: http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/online_help/Content/UG/ui_menu_test_parameters.htm